# Mount Logical Volume failing

Tags: mount, lvm

I'm trying to mount my logical volume and get the following error:

```
root@mediaserver:/home/jon# mount /dev/mediaserver/homeserver /media 
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

So I tried to specify ext4 type:

```
root@mediaserver:/home/jon# mount -t ext4 /dev/mediaserver/homeserver /media
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mediaserver-homeserver,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Then tried ext2:

```
root@mediaserver:/home/jon# mount -t ext2 /dev/mediaserver/homeserver /media
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mediaserver-homeserver,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Where do I go from here?  I have 4TB of data sitting there I can't get to.

Info requested:

```
ls -l /dev/mediaserver/homeserver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar  5 15:12 /dev/mediaserver/homeserver -> ../dm-2

file /dev/mediaserver/homeserver
/dev/mediaserver/homeserver: symbolic link to `../dm-2'
```

dmesg

```
[23509.241733] EXT2-fs (dm-2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev dm-2.
[23561.777635] EXT4-fs (dm-2): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[23569.175763] EXT2-fs (dm-2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev dm-2.
```

----More info requested:

```
jon@mediaserver:~$ sudo ls -lL /dev/mediaserver/homeserver
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252, 2 Mar  5 22:17 /dev/mediaserver/homeserver

jon@mediaserver:~$ sudo file -sL /dev/mediaserver/homeserver
/dev/mediaserver/homeserver: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xe, active, starthead
 0, startsector 551228337, 715429412 sectors; partition 2: ID=0xc, starthead 0, 
startsector 1287256334, 76756965 sectors; partition 3: ID=0x1, starthead 0,
startsector 1635111194, 16777344 sectors; partition 4: ID=0x7, starthead 0, 
startsector 1793823873, 20385300 sectors, code offset 0x31
```

Comment: Added output you requested above

Comment: Please update that to be the output of `ls -lL /dev/mediaserver/homeserver` and `file -sL /dev/mediaserver/homeserver`. We want to validate that the symlinks point to proper block devices.

Comment: Output added as requested by @zwets

Comment: check fstab navigate root>etc

Answer (score 2):

The output of `file -sL` shows that `/dev/mediaserver/homeserver` does not point to a file system, but to a disk image, i.e. a binary copy of an entire disk. The disk image apparently contains four partitions.

Use this command to find out the offset of each partition (in sector units) within the image:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/mediaserver/homeserver
```

Then, for each partition, convert the offset to bytes by multiplying by the sector size reported by fdisk, and pass this in the `offset` option to `mount`:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/part1
$ sudo mount -o offset=... /dev/mediaserver/homeserver /mnt/part1
```

That should get your data back. More info in [this article on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28436/how-to-mount-this-disk).

Comment: lvs:

`sudo lvs
  LV         VG          Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lvbackup   backup      -wi-ao 465.00g                                      
  homeserver mediaserver -wi-s-   8.99t 
`
But it won't mount:

`sudo mount /dev/mediaserver/homeserver /media
mount: special device /dev/mediaserver/homeserver does not exist`

Comment: I thought it was....how can I tell? And if it's not do I have any options? All I care about right now is getting to the data on those physical volumes.

Comment: You will get your data back. Completed the answer. If it works, please upvote, mark as solved and clean up comments. If it does not work, please carry over to unix.stackexchange.com because this is not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Or you can use `sudo kpartx -a /dev/mediaserver/homeserver` to parse the partition table and create the corresponding partition entries for you, which you can then mount.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for the `kpartx` tool (from the eponymous package). It should help you create and mount the partition from your disk image far more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was solved for me by using `e2fsck`.